# Ruby search for the same values in multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby, find

I have an array with many arrays inside (2d) (in this example there are four of them):

```
[
[13, 15, 18, 23, 23, 11, 14, 19, 19, 5, 10, 10, 8, 8], 
[8, 15, 19, 21, 21, 12, 16, 18, 18, 11, 13, 13, 6, 6], 
[9, 15, 21, 23, 23, 7, 13, 15, 15, 12, 14, 14, 8, 8], 
[2, 8, 14, 16, 16, 7, 13, 15, 15, 12, 14, 14, 8, 8]
]
```

I need to find if any element on any of these arrays is the same and at the same index as in other array. I need to get all those numbers and their indexes.

For ex. **First_array[1] = 15**, as well as **second_array[1] = 15** and **third_array[1] = 15**. So I need these, with their indexes.

Also all needed values must come from arrays that are to the left or to the right to the array. For ex. - **array_one[3] = 23**, **array_two[3] = 21** and **array_three[3] = 23**. I dont need these since array_two has a different value and it separates **array_one** from **array_three**.

And What I can get is the length of arrays (they all the same length) and the number of arrays, as variables.

I hope you got my point :)

---

Looks like I am abit closer to my goal. It seems this checks well for the second array (so only two first arrays being checked, but if this was done, the rest should be much easier). And do not judge me, judge just the code :D I know its ugly, its just a prototype:

```
array.each do |c|
   c.each do |v|
    c.each_with_index do |k, i|
      next_array = array[i + 1]
          if next_array.include? v 
            its_index = next_array.index(v) 
            if c.index(v) == its_index
            p v
          end
          end
        break
    end
   end 
   return
end
```

Comment: you did a good job describing what you need! however, you haven't posted any code showing your initial attempt. we're happy to help you get over a mental block or to find a bug in your code, but we don't give free from-scratch answers to prompts.

Comment: There are no multi-dimensional arrays in Ruby (unless you count `Matrix` from the standard library), just arrays of arrays and such.

Comment: @muistooshort: Technically, I guess you're correct. But what's wrong in considering an array of arrays as a 2D array?

Comment: Thanks all, my code is a bit messy - comments are all over etc, so will try to solve this by myself... But thanks anyway

Comment: @EricDuminil Because it isn't one? Because you can't work with an AoAoA... like a multi-dimensional array? Because most problems with them can be solved by understanding that you just have one-dimensional arrays nested within each other? Because sometimes I like to nitpick ()?

Comment: @muistooshort: What's an `AoAoA`? As far as I know, `int[][]` in Java is also just an array of arrays, yet it's called `2D` pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @EricDuminil "AoA" == "array of arrays", "AoAoA" == "array of arrays of arrays", ...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the desired result (as a Ruby object, such as an array or hash) whenever you give an example in a question. Also, please assign variables to all input objects (e.g., `arr = [[13, 15,...]`). That way readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. Also, they will all refer to the same variables (`arr`, rather than one using `array`, another `data`, and so on. That helps if readers want to test each other's code.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will keep this in mind for sure. About this question - I got your point. I am just starting to think as a programmer, when words and numbers become hashes, arrays, enums etc. And for now, I am just having fun solving my puzzle - creating a program that finds a Magical Square's number (at leas, at best - the square itself), from the given input. But I am not a matimttichian, I want to become a programmer, so I don't even have a good plan towards this goal - I just start coding my idea without a good plan and now I don't even remember well what was my problem :D

Comment: Just a note about replying to comments. When I left my comment you were informed by SO that someone left a comment for you. That's because it's your question. When you replied, however, I was not notified, I just happened to see it. Had you included "@CarySwoveland" in your comment I would have been notified. btw, your spell-checker seems to have a problem recognizing "matimttichian". :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Hm, ok. And I **was** informed about your last comment because it was under my post as I guess. Well thats a small step for you, one giant leap for me.. Thanks. And yeah, spell-checking was poor yesterday, as well as eye-watching...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = [[13, 15, 18, 23, 23, 11, 14, 19, 19,  5, 10, 10, 8, 8], 
       [ 8, 15, 19, 21, 23, 12, 16, 18, 19, 11, 13, 13, 6, 8], 
       [ 9, 15, 21, 23, 16, 12, 13, 15, 15, 12, 14, 14, 8, 8], 
       [ 2, 8,  14, 21, 16,  7, 13, 15, 15, 12, 14, 14, 8, 8]]
```

I've modified `arr` in a few places.

```
arr.transpose.each_with_index.with_object({}) do |(col,j),h|
  i = 0
  h[j] = col.chunk(&:itself).each_with_object({}) do |(x,arr),g|
    count = arr.size
    g.update(i=>{ value: x, number: count }) if count > 1
    i += count
  end
end
  #=> {0=>{},
  #    1=>{0=>{:value=>15, :number=>3}},
  #    2=>{},
  #    3=>{},
  #    4=>{0=>{:value=>23, :number=>2}, 2=>{:value=>16, :number=>2}},
  #    5=>{1=>{:value=>12, :number=>2}}
  #    6=>{2=>{:value=>13, :number=>2}},
  #    7=>{2=>{:value=>15, :number=>2}},
  #    8=>{0=>{:value=>19, :number=>2}, 2=>{:value=>15, :number=>2}},
  #    9=>{2=>{:value=>12, :number=>2}},
  #   10=>{2=>{:value=>14, :number=>2}},
  #   11=>{2=>{:value=>14, :number=>2}},
  #   12=>{2=>{:value=> 8, :number=>2}},
  #   13=>{0=>{:value=> 8, :number=>4}}}
```

The keys of this hash are indices of columns of `arr`. The values are hashes that contain the locations and counts of all vertically-adjacent elements which appear at least twice. The columns at indices `0`, `2` and `3`, are the only ones that contains no vertically-adjacent duplicate values. The column at index `1` contains `3` `15`'s beginning at row index `0`; the column at index `4` contains `2` `23`'s, beginning at row index `0` and `2` `16`'s, beginning at row index `2`.

Comment: sorry, but, this answer is wrong, in position 3 should not have return...

Take attention in the question's example. 

"For ex. - array_one[3] = 23, array_two[3] = 21 and array_three[3] = 23. I dont need these since array_two has a different value and it separates array_one from array_three."

probably he is working in a image processing algorithm, maybe border detection or something like that

Comment: @Frederic, I think it is OK now.

Comment: Cary, now it seems ok.. very nice code btw.

I did learnt alot with your code

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix = [
  [13, 15, 18, 23, 23, 11, 14, 19, 19,  5, 10, 10, 8, 8], 
  [ 8, 15, 19, 21, 21, 12, 16, 18, 18, 11, 13, 13, 6, 6], 
  [ 9, 15, 21, 23, 23,  7, 13, 15, 15, 12, 14, 14, 8, 8], 
  [ 2,  8, 14, 16, 16,  7, 13, 15, 15, 12, 14, 14, 8, 8]
]

equal_surround = matrix
  .each_with_index.map do |v,i| 
    v.each_with_index.map do |k,j| 
      if (i-1>=0 && k == matrix[i-1][j])
         k
      elsif (i+1 < matrix.length && k == matrix[i+1][j]) 
         k 
      else
         nil  
      end
    end
  end
=> [
  [nil,  15, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], 
  [nil,  15, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], 
  [nil,  15, nil, nil, nil,   7,  13,  15,  15,  12,  14,  14,   8,   8], 
  [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil,   7,  13,  15,  15,  12,  14,  14,   8,   8]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show any code, so I won't write any either.

I can tell you that [`array#transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) should make this problem much more manageable, though.

You'll just need to iterate on the rows (former columns) and look for any repeating number.

You can either do it FORTRAN style with a loop or with fancier [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html) methods, like [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index), [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) or [`chunk`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk).

Comment: Thx, your advices will be written down and examined :)

Answer (score 0):

```
test_array = [
[13, 15, 18, 23, 23, 11, 14, 19, 19, 5, 10, 10, 8, 8], 
[8, 15, 19, 21, 21, 12, 16, 18, 18, 11, 13, 13, 6, 6], 
[9, 15, 21, 23, 23, 7, 13, 15, 15, 12, 14, 14, 8, 8], 
[2, 8, 14, 16, 16, 7, 13, 15, 15, 12, 14, 14, 8, 8]
]
final_res = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Array.new }

test_array.each_cons(2).to_a.each_with_index  do |(a,b),i|

    final_match = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Array.new }

    res = a & b

    res.each do |ele|

        a_index = a.each_index.select{|i| a[i] == ele}
        b_index = b.each_index.select{|i| b[i] == ele}

        (a_index &  b_index).size > 0 ? final_match[ele] << (a_index &  b_index) : ''

    end

    final_match.each_value {|v| v.flatten!}

    final_res[:"Match Values Between Array #{i+1} amd Array #{i+2}"] << final_match

end 

final_res.each do |a|

puts a

end
```

OUTPUT:

Match Values Between Array 1 amd Array 2
{15=>[1]}

Match Values Between Array 2 amd Array 3
{15=>[1]}

Match Values Between Array 3 amd Array 4
{15=>[7, 8], 7=>[5], 13=>[6], 12=>[9], 14=>[10, 11], 8=>[12, 13]}

Comment: Thx, I will examine it more tomorrow, but at first sight, seems its not quite working. But maybe I am wrong

Comment: `map` is creating multiple unnecessary Array's in this code since all you are retaining is `final_match`. I did not vet this code any further other than `each` could be used in place of `map` to avoid needless overhead

Comment: shoot..! I missed the index part of the question ,was thinking to get the values alone. Have updated the code to include index too. @engineersmnky as per you suggestion have updated the `map` with `each`. would like suggestion on the code if there are issues.